# Getting list of selection listeners in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, listeners

I want to get all of the list selection listeners that are registered with the selection model in my `JTable`, but I don't see a method to get them.  Is there a way I can retrieve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use the [getSelectionModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29) method on a new JTable
2. cast the result to the DefaultListSelectionModel
3. use the [getListSelectionListeners()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html#getListSelectionListeners%28%29)

hope it helps!